# Change integer in bitset

Tags: c++, std-bitset

How does one change the integer being used by `bitset`? Suppose I used `bitset` to declare a variable `mybitset` which stores the bits of a number, say 32. After doing some operations, I want `mybitset` to store the bits of some other number, say 63. How do I achieve this?

I have added a small piece of sample code below to help explain.

```
bitset<32> mybits(32);
....
mybits(63);  // gives compilation error here, stating "no match for call to '(std::bitset<32u>) (uint&)'"
```

I feel there should be some straightforward method to do this, but haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use

```
mybits = bitset<32>(63);
```

as other answers have pointed out, or simply

```
mybits = 63;
```

The latter works because 63 is implicitly convertible to a `bitset<32>` (as the constructor from `long` is not marked as `explicit`). It does the same thing as the first version, but is a bit less verbose.

Answer (score 3):

As from the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

> `bitset` meets the requirements of [`CopyConstructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyConstructible) and [`CopyAssignable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable).

Thus you can simply assign from another `std::bitset` matching the same template parameter signature:

```
bitset<32> mybits(32);
// ....
mybits = bitset<32>(63);
```

or use one of the implicit constructors (2) along lvalue type deduction:

> ```
> bitset( unsigned long val ); // (until C++11)
> constexpr bitset( unsigned long long val );
> ```

and assign the value directly:

```
mybits = 63;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call:
`myBits = std::bitset<32>{63};`

Answer (score 1):

A [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) is copy assignable, so you make a new one with the desired value and assign that to the bitset you want to change:

```
bitset<32> mybitset{21};
mybitset = bitset<32>{42};
```

If you don't want to specify the type once again, you could use `decltype` or even better the fact that bitsets constructor isn't explicit:

```
mybitset = {42};
```

(In [action)](http://ideone.com/Gfp8fP)